# thread and creating object

Tags: java, multithreading, redundancy

I am trying to learn about thread and find some examples in the internet. This is a java class that output "hello, world" every 3 seconds. But I have a feeling that the part about creating a Runable object is redundant.

Instead of writing

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){ public void run(){...some actions...}};
```

Can I put the method `run()` somewhere else for easy reading?

This is what I have:

```
public class TickTock extends Thread {
    public static void main (String[] arg){
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    while (true) {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                    System.err.println("Message printer interrupted");
                }
            }
        };
      Thread thr = new Thread(r);
      thr.start();
}
```

And this is what I want to accomplish

```
public static void main (String[] arg){ 
          Runnable r = new Runnable() //so no run() method here, 
                                  //but where should I put run()
          Thread thr = new Thread(r);
          thr.start();
    }
```

Comment: In addition to actual answers below, consider learning how to use refactoring tools of your IDE for doing things like this (turning anonymous classes into inner classes or "normal" non-nested classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I put the method run() somewhere else for easy reading?

Yes you could create your own runnable like this

```
public class CustomRunnable implements Runnable{
// put run here
}
```

and then

```
Runnable r = new CustomRunnable () ;
Thread thr = new Thread(r);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Java threads tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html), you can use a slightly different style:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your anonymous `Runnable` class an inner static class, like so:

```
public class TickTock {

    public static void main (String[] arg){
        Thread thr = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        thr.start();
    }

    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        public void run(){
            try{
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                System.err.println("Message printer interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or since `TickTock` already extends `Thread` in your example code, you can just override its `run` method:

```
public class TickTock extends Thread {

    public static void main (String[] arg){
        Thread thr = new TickTock();
        thr.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("Hello, world!");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            System.err.println("Message printer interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```